# Spring Kafka - increase in concurrency produces more duplicate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Topic A created with 12 partition ,
And spring Kafka consumer started with 10 concurrency as spring boot application. While putting 1000 message into topic , there is no issues with duplicate as all 1000 messages got consumed but on pushing more load 10K messages 100TPS , in consumer end received 10K + 8.5K messages as duplicate with 10 concurrency but for one concurrency it's working fine ( No duplicates found )

Enable auto commit is false and doing manual ack after processing the message .

Processing time for one message is 300 milli second

Consumer rebalance occuring because of that duplicates got produced.

How to overcome this situation when we are handling more message in Kafka ?

Comment: What is your consumer application configuration? I don't think there is a problem on the producer side, so would be great to have some consumer project from you to play with.

Comment: Are you really getting duplicates? Or is your listener not thread-safe? If you are getting a rebalance due to a slow consumer, reduce `max.poll.records` or increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: artem Bilan , enable auto commit is false at consumer config and listener concurrency as 10 , remaining config are default

Comment: Hi Gary , yes on huge load am getting more duplicates almost 80% of the messages got duplicated , yea tried reducing max.poll.record to 50 and 200 , it got no duplicate for 50 and few duplicate for 200 but this reduces the performance . I need to have no duplicates with high performance . Looking for EOS at consumer end with good performance

Comment: Is the producer using transactions or have idempotence enabled?

Comment: Idempotence is enabled at producer end and enable auto commit is false , isolation level is read committed at consumer end